# Copy contents of an int array to a double array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, double

I'm trying to copy the contents of my int array into an array of type double.  Do I have to cast them first?

I successfully copied an array of type int to another array of type int.
However now I want to write code that would copy contents from Array `A` to Array `Y` (int to double).

Here is my code:

```
public class CopyingArraysEtc {

    public void copyArrayAtoB() {
        double[] x = {10.1,33,21,9},y = null;
        int[] a = {23,31,11,9}, b = new int[4], c;

        System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }

    }          

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //copy contents of Array A to array B
        new CopyingArraysEtc().copyArrayAtoB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? does it work? do you get any errors? Not entirely sure what the question is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can iterate through each element of the source and add them to the destination array. You don't need an explicit cast going from `int` to `double` because `double` is wider.

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
double[] doubles = new double[ints.length];
for(int i=0; i<ints.length; i++) {
    doubles[i] = ints[i];
}
```

You can make a utility method like this -

```
public static double[] copyFromIntArray(int[] source) {
    double[] dest = new double[source.length];
    for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for taking the time to explain that :) Its exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 28):

Worth mentioning that in this day and age, Java 8 offers an elegant one-liner to do this without the need to use third-party libraries:

```
int[] ints = {23, 31, 11, 9};
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(ints).asDoubleStream().toArray();
```

Comment: This could be a performance hog if you do that thousands/millions of times. Creating many streams of only a few items can degrade performance.

Answer (score 13):

`System.arraycopy()` can't copy `int[]` to `double[]`

How about using google guava:

```
int[] a = {23,31,11,9};

//copy int[] to double[]
double[] y=Doubles.toArray(Ints.asList(a));
```

Answer (score 6):

From [System.arraycopy JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

> [...] Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an **ArrayStoreException** is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> *...
>
> *...
>
> *The src argument and dest argument refer to arrays whose component types are **different primitive types**.
> [...]

Since `int` and `double` are different primitive types you will have to manually iterate through one array and copy its content to another one.