# How to cast int[] to double[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I would like to know how to do something like this in java:

```
int[] integerArray = {1,2,3};
double[] doubleArray =(double) integerArray;
```

I know this is possible for single values, but it seems impossible for arrays.
How should I do this? 
I would prefer ways that don't require me to write loops.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Oliver Charlesworths link if found this useful anser:

Worth mentioning that in this day and age, Java 8 offers an elegant one-liner to do this without the need to use third-party libraries:

```
int[] ints = {23, 31, 11, 9};
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(ints).asDoubleStream().toArray();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729139/copy-contents-of-an-int-array-to-a-double-array-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Create an IntStream, mapToDouble to get a DoubleStream, and convert back with toArray().

Comment: Good one with the streaming. However Arrays.stream() will not work with a float[]....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly. you need to iterate on each element and convert it to double.

```
int[] integerArray = {1, 2, 3};
double[] doubleArray = new double[integerArray.length];
for(int i=0; i<integerArray.length; i++) {
    doubleArray[i] = integerArray[i];
}
```